# SwiftUI Button's respond to touches outside their drawn bounds

Tags: swift, uibutton, swiftui, swiftui-list

I've created a styled button using `ButtonStyle`. I use this button in my views like so.

`Button("Cancel", action: onCancel).buttonStyle(FormButtonStyle(mode: .normal)`

In some places I add padding to the button above

`.padding(.init(arrayLiteral: .trailing, .leading), 16)`

However these buttons respond to touch events outside their drawn bounds. How do i prevent this from happening? In example below touches on `cancel` will trigger the `save` button. This happens with or without the padding. Most of these buttons sit at the bottom of a `List` used to select multiple items. For example in my app I have an `Save` and `Cancel` button.

```
private var actionBtns: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8){
            Divider().foregroundColor(Color.veryLightPinkThree)
            Button("Save", action: onSave).buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(mode: .normal))
                .padding(.init(arrayLiteral: .trailing, .leading), 16)
            Button("Cancel", action: onCancel).buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(mode: .success))
                .padding(.init(arrayLiteral: .trailing, .leading), 16)
        }
        .backgroundColor(.offWhite)
    }
```

This `actionsBtns` view is added to the body of my SwiftUI view.

```
import PureSwiftUI
import SwiftUI


struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    enum Weight {
        case normal
        case compact

        func fontSize() -> Double {
            switch self {
            default:
                return 16.0
            }
        }

        func hPadding() -> CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .normal:
                return 16.0

            case .compact:
                return 16.0
            }
        }

        func height() -> CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .normal:
                return 56.0

            case .compact:
                return 40.0
            }
        }

        func width() -> CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .normal:
                return 150.0
            case .compact:
                return 75.0

            }
        }

    }

    enum Mode {
        case normal
        case success
        case destroy
        case greenOutline
        case dark

        func foregroundColor(isEnabled: Bool = true) -> Color {
            switch self {
            case .success, .dark, .destroy:
                return Color.white

            case .greenOutline:
                return  isEnabled  ? .mediumGreen : .veryLightPinkFour

            default:
                return isEnabled ? Color.greyishBrown : Color.white
            }
        }

        func backgroundColor(isEnabled: Bool = true) -> Color {
            switch self {
            case .destroy:
                return isEnabled ? Color.pinkishOrange : Color.veryLightPinkThree

            case .success:
                return isEnabled ? Color.mediumGreen : Color.veryLightPinkThree

            case .greenOutline:
                return .white

            case .dark:
                return Color.greyishBrown

            default:
                return isEnabled ? Color.offWhite : Color.veryLightPinkThree
            }
        }

        func strokeColor(isEnabled: Bool = true) -> Color {
            switch self {
            case .normal:
                return isEnabled ? Color.veryLightPinkThree: Color.veryLightPinkTwo

            case .greenOutline:
                return .mediumGreen

            default:
                return Color.clear
            }
        }
    }

    var mode: Mode = .normal
    var weight: Weight = .normal

    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        CustomButton(configuration: configuration, mode: mode, weight: weight)
    }

    struct CustomButton: View {
        @SwiftUI.Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool

        var configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration
        var mode: FormButtonStyle.Mode
        var weight: FormButtonStyle.Weight

        init(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration, mode: FormButtonStyle.Mode, weight: FormButtonStyle.Weight) {
            self.configuration = configuration
            self.mode = mode
            self.weight = weight
        }


        var body: some View {
            configuration.label
            .lineLimit(1)
            .greedyWidth()
            .height(weight.height())
            .padding(.horizontal, weight.hPadding())
            .fontSize(weight.fontSize(), weight: .bold)
            .foregroundColor(mode.foregroundColor(isEnabled: isEnabled))
            .backgroundColor(mode.backgroundColor(isEnabled: isEnabled))
            .clipRoundedRectangleWithStroke(weight.height() / 2.0, mode.strokeColor(isEnabled: isEnabled), lineWidth: 1)
            .compositingGroup()
        }
}
```

Comment: Provided code is not testable due to absent many custom dependencies.

Comment: try adding ".contentShape(Rectangle())" to you Buttons

Comment: @workingdog I have tried that with no luck.

Comment: without simple example code we could paste and run, the only thing I could say: `.contentShape()` Is the very instrument you need.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you checked your view hierarchy?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `List` and a button inside each row set `.buttonStyle(.borderless)`.

Comment: This indeed worked in my case.